# MySQL issue in getting average of a column

Tags: mysql, database, select, average

I have a MySQL table having three columns id, name and height.

I want to run a query to return the name and height of all entries, along with the average height of all entries. All these things have to be done in a single query.

This is what I tried.

```
SELECT name, height, avg(height) as average_height FROM mytable
```

This query returns only a single row, but the average height is correct.

```
name    height    average_height
--------------------------------
Harry   165       169.5
```

then I tried this query

```
SELECT name, height, avg(height) as average_height FROM mytable GROUP BY name
```

then it returns all the rows, but the average is not correct

```
name    height    average_height
--------------------------------
Harry   165       165
Tom     170       170
George  180       180
Raj     163       163
```

How can I get the average as well as all the rows in a single query.

Comment: Those are two different functions (an aggregate and a list) at best you could union two separate queries and hack the average in as the first/last row, but since you're looking up all the information anyway, why not just calculate the average outside of MySQL?

Comment: @Rudu, it's not hard at all to produce the desired result with a join or subquery, as several answers have shown.  It's no problem from a technical standpoint.  And while it's not clear why the OP wants this, there are plenty of cases in which an operation like this makes sense.  For example, if you want a column that lists a person's height relative to the average, you would need to join the average height to each row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
SELECT name, height, average_height FROM mytable CROSS JOIN (
   select avg(height) as average_height FROM mytable
) as avg;
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4feb/4) (Updated example to reflect suggestion to use `CROSS JOIN`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, height, average_height 
FROM mytable, (SELECT AVG(height) average_height FROM mytable) A
```

**OR**

```
SELECT name, height, (SELECT AVG(height) FROM mytable) AS average_height 
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 2):

During first query you are asking the avg height and it's printing average height against the first record(Harry). In second query you are asking for avg of heights of all students in a group who are grouped on their names. Now in your case you have four groups, each containing only one record, as there is no duplicate name, so average height of one record will come as height of that record itself.

What you want to do is to print each record and against it, print avg height.

```
SELECT name, height, (SELECT AVG(height) FROM mytable) AS average_height 
FROM mytable;
```